# this.optionalCall is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

./node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esnext/components/hotkeys/hotkeysTarget.js
TypeError: app/client/node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/esnext/components/hotkeys/hotkeysTarget.js: this.optionalCall is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Add more context when asking questions, like writing code snippets that fail. I see you are a new contributor, but please take a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust your question.